# Could not resolve type id 'http' as a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.jetty.ConnectorFactory]

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dropwizard

I'm using dropwizard in my app, and i attempt to run the JAR file it shows me the following error:

```
Could not resolve type id 'http' as a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.jetty.ConnectorFactory]
```

My config.yml file

```
server:
  type: default
  applicationConnectors:
  - type: http
    port: 9000
  adminConnectors:
  - type: http
    port: 9001
```

Also, i've handled the shadow plugin in my build.gradle, but still show me the error.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.1"
    }
}


apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = "com.freightos.flux.LocationsApplication"

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "4.5"
}

// Configure the shadow jar task
shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: How did you eventually solve it?

Answer (score -1):

The indention of your YAML looks broken. A [linter](http://www.yamllint.com/) returns this for it:

```
server: 
  adminConnectors: 
    - 
      port: 9001
      type: http
  applicationConnectors: 
    - 
      port: 9000
      type: http
  type: default
```

Try this instead:

```
server:
  type: default
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8081
    - type: https
```

Comment: the same as above

Comment: Could not resolve type id 'http' as a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.jetty.ConnectorFactory]